# jquery selectmenu variable in php via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to get a jquery (a selectmenu) variable to php. I try it with Ajax "POST". For testing purpose i just want to echo out the selected number of the selectmenu without any page refresh. So the Change should appear dynamically.

Here is my **html_file.php**

```
<script>  $( function() {
    $( "#number" )
      .selectmenu()
      .selectmenu( "menuWidget" )
        .addClass( "overflow" );

      $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "php_file.php",
                data: { number }
            })

       /* Here we receive the data back */
            .done(function(data) {
                /* Here you can do whatever you want with the data */
               $("#response").html(data);
            });

  } );

</script>

<select name="number" id="number">
  <option>1</option>
  <option selected="selected">2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  </select>

<div id='response'></div>
```

And here the **php_file.php**

```
<?php

$test = $_POST['number'];

// Output of the selcetmenu for testing

echo '<div class="profile-font2">', $test, '</div>';

?>
```

I think there is some mistake in the Ajax function.

Comment: PASS AS ajax => data: { number : YOUR_number }

Answer (score 0):

Pass key as `number` and assign value to number key as

```
        $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "php_file.php",
                data: { number : yournumber }
            })
```

Comment: I don´t want to give a fixed number. If I change in the selectmenu a number it should be dynamically changed  without page reloading. For example if I switch from the selected number 2 in number 3 i want to get this echo out dynamically.

Comment: Yeah but I need the selected number dynamically set as a value. So if I chose in the selectmenu 2 it should appear the 2. I don´t want to set it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your data property a value.

**Try:**

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "php_file.php",
  data: {
    number: $("#number").val()
  }
})
```

Comment: is this still actual then in the php Code? $test = $_POST['number'];

Comment: You can get the passed number value using $_POST['number']. So you're php file is correct.